# Confusion between Drawable, View and Surface in the scenario below

Tags: android, android-canvas, drawable

I'm a bit confused how Drawable, View and Surfaces should be used in Android. Imagine the following scenario: One main view that can be zoomed (pinch zoom) and on which the user can tab at any point. Everywhere the user tabs I want to add a pre-defined shape and connect all of them by a line.

So I need a zoomable main view which I draw myself in onDraw() method. Then I need to define my drawable in a XML file that will visualize my tab-position and draw that on each of the tabbed position in the view?

I would be glad if you can point me into the right direction how to realize the above scenario the right way.

Comment: Please don't prefix your question's titles with stuff like `Android:`, `How to:`, there are tags at the bottom and it just adds clutter. Also, tab == tap?

Comment: Yeah, you are right. Thanks for reminding me. Tab = finger tab